# cors issue in post request while deploying laravel inside docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx, cors

I have a laravel app which is running behind [nginx proxy manager](https://nginxproxymanager.com/). The [laravel app](https://api.codalay.in) is running inside a docker container and [nuxt frontend](https://codalay.in) is also running inside another docker container. Laravel is using **fortify**, **sanctum** packages for authentication and session validation.

The issue is that when i try to login using a fake user. then all preflight request, get request works perfectly fine. but when i try to make a **post request for login**, then it seems to work perfectly fine. as response status is 200 as in header. but says that `Access Control Allow Origin` header is missing, **which causes no response to show up.**

what i am missing. where is the issue? this seems to be a common problem.

#### methods to reproduce.

- try to login with any email id & password, which ideally should throw 422 error along with validation error messages. but instead comes 200 with no script/ cors error

#### I have already tried.

- i added following in my laravel nginx deployment configuration which seems to solve post problem but then when user details is fetched using `/api/user`(default sanctum user). then 401 issue comes. this doesn't seem to be a valid answer. (

```
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        if ( $request_method = POST ) {          
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://codalay.in';         
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true'; 
        }
    }
```

- another way i tried is i added following code in api.codalay.in's reverse proxy nginx configuration . then cors error changes

```
# custom headers required for cors issues for laravel.
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin origin;
add_header Access-Control-Max-Age 3600;
add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers Content-Length;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers Range;
```

and throws

```
Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match 'https://codalay.in'
```

I am trying to fix this issue from 10 days. please help

**Edit 1: added my configurations files**
backend `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

networks:
  laravel:
  nginx_reverse_proxy:
    external: true

services:
  codalay-nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx-codalay
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - codalay-php
      - codalay-mysql
    networks:
      - laravel
      - nginx_reverse_proxy

  codalay-mysql:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: codalay
      MYSQL_USER: rex
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'somerandomstring'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'somerandomstring'
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - laravel
      - nginx_reverse_proxy

  codalay-php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - laravel
      - nginx_reverse_proxy

  composer:
    image: composer:latest
    container_name: composer
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - codalay-php
    networks:
      - laravel
      - nginx_reverse_proxy

  npm:
    image: node:16
    container_name: npm
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: [ 'npm' ]
    networks:
      - nginx_reverse_proxy

  codalay-artisan:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: artisan
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - codalay-mysql
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: [ 'php', '/var/www/html/artisan' ]
    networks:
      - laravel
      - nginx_reverse_proxy
```

#### backend nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        # if ( $request_method = POST ) {          
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://codalay.in';         
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true'; 
        # }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_read_timeout 240;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }


}
```

#### reverse-proxy nginx configuration

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------
# api.codalay.in
# ------------------------------------------------------------


server {
  set $forward_scheme http;
  set $server         "nginx-codalay";
  set $port           80;

  listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;


  server_name api.codalay.in;


  # Let's Encrypt SSL
  include conf.d/include/letsencrypt-acme-challenge.conf;
  include conf.d/include/ssl-ciphers.conf;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/npm-4/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/npm-4/privkey.pem;




# Asset Caching
  include conf.d/include/assets.conf;


  # Block Exploits
  include conf.d/include/block-exploits.conf;



  # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (63072000 seconds = 2 years)
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000;includeSubDomains; preload" always;
  add_header Referrer-Policy strict-origin-when-cross-origin; 
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
  add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
  add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
  add_header Content-Security-Policy upgrade-insecure-requests;
  add_header Permissions-Policy interest-cohort=();
  add_header Expect-CT 'enforce; max-age=604800';
  more_set_headers 'Server: Proxy';
  more_clear_headers 'X-Powered-By';




# custom headers required for cors issues for laravel.
# add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin origin;
# add_header Access-Control-Max-Age 3600;
# add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers Content-Length;
# add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers Range;

# proxy_redirect                      off;
# proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
# proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
# proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
# proxy_read_timeout                  3600;
# proxy_connect_timeout               3600;

# proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
# proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
# proxy_set_header Host $host;
# proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;


    # Force SSL
    include conf.d/include/force-ssl.conf;




proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
proxy_http_version 1.1;


  access_log /data/logs/proxy-host-11_access.log proxy;
  error_log /data/logs/proxy-host-11_error.log warn;







  location / {

    



  # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (63072000 seconds = 2 years)
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000;includeSubDomains; preload" always;
  add_header Referrer-Policy strict-origin-when-cross-origin; 
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
  add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
  add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
  add_header Content-Security-Policy upgrade-insecure-requests;
  add_header Permissions-Policy interest-cohort=();
  add_header Expect-CT 'enforce; max-age=604800';
  more_set_headers 'Server: Proxy';
  more_clear_headers 'X-Powered-By';




# custom headers required for cors issues for laravel.
# add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin origin;
# add_header Access-Control-Max-Age 3600;
# add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers Content-Length;
# add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers Range;

# proxy_redirect                      off;
# proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
# proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
# proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
# proxy_read_timeout                  3600;
# proxy_connect_timeout               3600;

# proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
# proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
# proxy_set_header Host $host;
# proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;


    
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    

    # Proxy!
    include conf.d/include/proxy.conf;
  }


  # Custom
  include /data/nginx/custom/server_proxy[.]conf;
}
```

---

### edit 2: I am using laravel 9

Comment: did you used both diff domain ? for api and main app?

Comment: location /api/ {
        proxy_pass {apidomain comes here} 
    }

Comment: @ShashikantChauhan i have added configuraiton files as well. my frontend code is hosted on different subdomains. pl tell if you need to know that too?

Comment: See prefetch request will gave lot of more issue with speed also. Use above solution i am using that .. see you have to setup subdomain api server and pass that above solution in current project change url as domain.com/api/ it will work

Comment: @ShashikantChauhan. I am working on your advice now. I have exhausted myself more than enough in doing setup.

Comment: Here I am sharing my conf you can use it as ref. may be it will help you.

Answer (score -1):

Hello Here is my laravel conf for nginx.

```
server {
    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    root /pathtoproject/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name domainname;
    
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;


}


server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    #listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /var/www/keys/bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/keys/*.domain.key;



    root /pathtoproject/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name domainname.com;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    charset utf-8;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 1800;
        # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
         proxy_read_timeout 5m; 

    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
    
}
```

Here is my anguler side script for working setup. use api access as domain.com/api/

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name maindomain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

}
server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    ssl_certificate /var/www/keys/bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/keys/*.domain.key;


    server_name maindomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4400;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
    
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass https://api.domain.com;
    }
    location /storage/ {
        proxy_pass https://api.domain.com;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this. i ended up doing someting similar as you said. but since this is not actual answer. i am leaving this open for future. in case i find i will update.